# gridview cell text is blank after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using bound fields and inspecting cell text in rowdatabound event. When it's not a postback there's something in cell text. But when I cause a postback cell text is blank but it doesn't show blank on the display (e.Row.Cells[2].Text is what I'm inspecting below)

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text != tbUserName.Text)
        {
            LinkButton b = e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
            b.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = _dbc.Tasks.ToList();        
    GridView1.DataSource = tasks;
    GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

Comment: Can you tell where you bind gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was user error! I had some code in another area modifying the columns unexpectedly, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track whether page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback. Currently gridview is binded again and again on every postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      IEnumerable<Task> tasks = _dbc.Tasks.ToList();        
      GridView1.DataSource = tasks;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
}
```